# Workflow: render an animation with a soundtrack in one go, or render the animation then import it as a strip in the VSE?

Tags: animation, workflow, audio

I am creating an animation with a soundtrack. I have a 3D window open with a timeline, and a VSE window open with the audio synced so I can time the animation with the sound. Can I render the finished product, a video file (sound and animation) from this setup? I have not found a way to do this.

Rather, it seems like I have to break the process up into two parts:
First: create the 3D animation and render it to either images or a video file format.
Second: import the rendered animation into a strip in the VSE, import the audio, then render the final product.

Is this correct, or am I missing something?

Comment: you can do it in one go, you have to select an audio codec under Output Properties > Output > Encoding > Audio

Comment: Thanks, that was perfect. Just the info I needed.